# Products saleables only in some stores - Magento

Tags: magento

I'd like to know if there is a way to make products not saleable (but visible) in some store views. For example: I have two stores (not websites not views): StoreA and StoreB.

Both stores share the same catalog, but when you're in StoreB you can only see products, not buying them (not add to cart button should be shown).

Has magento any functionality like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the available quantity to 0 in the shops where you only want to display the product.

Cheers
k

Comment: Hi bigkthx, the problem is that the quantiy is a Global attribute, so it can't be set per store.

Comment: i think it is possible to set the scope of products in general in your system configuration... System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Price -> Price Scope to "Website". The disadvantage is that you need to have different websites inside your magento not just stores/store-views.

Comment: Well, stock is global and cannot be changed. Changing the price is not useful here :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with category permissions. Go to Manage Categories in the Admin, select the category of the list of products you don't want prices or add-to-cart shown on, then go to the Permissions tab. You can set permissions based on store and/or customer group.